# Can I connect to an Oracle database (just to use a select query) using PHP 5.1.6 on Linux?

Tags: php, oracle

I tried below:

```
<?php
    $db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = acmdf3kdjgf)(PORT = 1221)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = SCCF5)(SRVR = DEDICATED)))";


    if($c = OCILogon("asfjdf", "dafdff", $db))
    {
        echo "Successfully connected to Oracle.\n";
        OCILogoff($c);
    }
    else
    {
        $err = OCIError();
        echo "Connection failed." . $err[text];
    }
?>
```

I am getting following error:

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function OCILogon() in /test/testscrpts/connectOracleDb.php on line 5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check if you activate `OCI8` extension in PHP.

Check this link to install : http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php

Secondly, `OCILogon` is **deprecated since PHP 5.4** : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ocilogon.php , you should use `oci_connect` instead http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php

Comment: How do I activate OCI8 extension in PHP on GNU/Linux?

Comment: You can install PECL from OCI8.  Check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html